# gnuplot autoscale data series on different systems

Tags: raspberry-pi, gnuplot, ubuntu-14.04

I want to use gnuplot as a plotting engine on a raspberry pi based web server. However, gnuplot seems to behave differently when used on ubuntu 14.04 and raspberry.
Difference seen is in plots built from same data with same (some path modified) command files. Main problem here is on the raspberry pi the x-range is cut off (and artefact points occasionally). The est. last45 minutes are cut of.

Gnuplot is started via python subprocess and when provoked delivers an error message, through appropriate channel, however I am not be seeing error messages regarding the problem.

Any ideas where to start looking ?
Thx !

commands used:

```
set term png size 1200,800 
set output "/var/www/plot.png" 
set xdata time 
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S" 
set format x "%H:%M" 
set xrange ["00:00:00":"24:00:00"] 
set title "Temperatures as logged 26.06.14" 
set xlabel "Uhrzeit [UTC]" 
plot "/var/www/plotdat.dat" using 1:2 title "Temp" with line
```

ubuntu 14.04:

```
G N U P L O T
Version 4.6 patchlevel 4    last modified 2013-10-02 
Build System: Linux i686
```

raspberry pi

```
G N U P L O T
Version 4.6 patchlevel 0    last modified 2012-03-04 
Build System: Linux armv6l
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the datafiles are identical on both platforms? Also, the png output is provided by the `gd` library. So its version might be relevant as well. If possible, try to install the same patchlevel both systems.

Comment: Hi Roland ! Datafile: when noticing the different plots, this was the first check: I transfered one datafile via sftp and checked via editor (line numbers, contents of first and last 4 lines) - they look identical. As the png is well-formed I'd exclude the "gd" for now. Which leaves the patchlevel of gnuplot. As I am not really familiar with compiling from source this will take some time but needs to be done. Thanks for your comments !

Comment: If you want to check differences, use the `diff` program. It is probably available on all UNIX/Linux variants. Another difference is the hardware architecture and presumably the compiler. Several Linux distributions have build infrastructure for programs, i.e. Makefiles or equivalent to build programs from source to make packages. Maybe you can use one of those.

Comment: Hi Roland, I am aware of diff an other bin compare utilities, however the transfered (via sftp) file is what I am using. I plan now to go to gnuplot to get a later source/patchlevel and try my luck there. Thanks !

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay, family, job... Just a summary of what has happend: build gnuplot V4.6 patchlevel 4 from source on raspberry successfully, works identical to th when operated from commandline. Then found my problems are connected with calling gnuplot via Popen in python. Therefor have to investigate in new directions. Will close this thread as this needs a rethink and does not fit topic anyway. Thanks for your support !

Comment: I would use `subprocess.check_call()` instead of `Popen` in a use case such as this, unless you _really_ need gnuplot to read from stdin for some reason. But if you let gnuplot read its data from files, you can check and verify that it works outside of Python.

Comment: working ! subprocess.call() did the trick. Finally there. Learned a lot. Thanks !